# PCIe 4.0 NVMe Bottleneck on Asus ROG Crosshair Hero VIII

Tags: pci-express, nvme, m.2, amd-ryzen

I have an AMD RYZEN 5800x and AMD RADEON 6900 XT atop an Asus ROG Crosshair Hero VIII occupied with one M.2 SSD in the top M.2 slot and four 2.5" SSDs in the top 4 of 8 SATA ports. 
 
Also, I have a PCIe USB 3x expansion card connected to the PCIe x1 slot below the top x16 slot. In addition to this, all of my USB headers are occupied. 
 
The motherboard has a second M.2 slot I want to occupy. Given my current five storage devices, GPU, and USB expansion card, do you see any potential bottleneck issues between the PCIe lanes now and/or after adding a second M.2?

I'm just not finding this information in the manual: 
https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-crosshair/rog-crosshair-viii-hero-wi-fi-model/
 
Here you will find the PCIe table for gen 3 Ryzen. *It didn't have a gen 4 table.

Also, it didn't mention the PCIe x1 slot. I'm worried my my GPU may be downcasted from x16 lanes because of my PCIe x1 slot USB expansion card. Is this a potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, it didn't mention the PCIe x1 slot. I'm worried my my GPU may be downcasted from x16 lanes because of my PCIe x1 slot USB expansion card. Is this a potential?

No; The manual for your motherboard does not explicitly say this will happen.

> Here you will find the PCIe table for gen 3 Ryzen. *It didn't have a gen 4 table.

The only table that exist in the manual specifically specifies which PCIe and M.2 slots support PCIe Gen 4.  **The PCIe x1 slot does not support PCIe Gen 4.**

> The motherboard has a second M.2 slot I want to occupy. Given my current five storage devices, GPU, and USB expansion card, do you see any potential bottleneck issues between the PCIe lanes now and/or after adding a second M.2?

The only potential performance you might have seen is an inability to use the second M.2 while using a specific PCIe slot.  **The manual does NOT specify that is the case, which means, that all M.2 and PCIe slots can be used.**

> So does the PCIe x1 slot have any effect on the other PCIe 4.0 slots?

The PCIe x1 slot only supports PCIe Gen 3 according to the manual for your motherboard.